# JavaScript code not working in HTML page but it works in Console

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, console

I am trying to add JavaScript code to show and hide some content with JQuery to my HTML page. When I add it in HTML code or in javaScript file with .js or in head or footer block the code is added and show in HTML code but it is not working. But when I add to test my same code in the console in the developer tool(Inspect) the code is working. I can't understand what is the issue. I am working on the page: https://radiusofficefurniture.ie/jemini-intro-1200-modular-straight-base-unit-maple-1200masama--1
The code is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var lenth_2 = $('.add_to_cart_custom .delivery--information').children().length;
    if( lenth_2 > 1 ){
        $('.add_to_cart_custom .delivery--information').hide();
        $("p.delivery_custom").parent('.add_to_cart_custom .delivery--information').show();
        $(".product_specs2 .item.attr_item_lead_time").hide();
    }
});
```

And also when I add some other JS code to this page for other functionality the same issue occurs.
And the issue only appears only on single products pages that have the same layout. For other pages, JS works when I add in Html.

Comment: Could be that your `.delivery--information` (etc) is not loaded with the page, but loaded after the page has loaded via an ajax call.   F12 in your browser and select the network tab, then reload the page.  You should see an initial page load to the server, then various images/scripts/css.  You may then see other requests to the server.  (**edit**: quick look at the page in question and there's *huge* amounts of post render content, it's very likely in one or more of them)

Comment: Thanks,
that's work. Now I have used the setTimeout function.

Comment: Ensure that your jQuery selectors match the actual structure of your HTML. If the elements you are trying to select do not exist, the code won't work.

For example, make sure that .add_to_cart_custom .delivery--information and .product_specs2 .item.attr_item_lead_time are valid selectors based on your HTML structure. and also Use jQuery Instead of $